# Flask restless preprocessor "DELETE_RESOURCE" does not get invoked

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, preprocessor

Hi I have Javascript client that makes the following url
http://127.0.0.1:2500/api/sdk_prodinfo/abcde, (where abcde is the primary key for a table "sdk_prodinfo" on the server side)

I have registered the api on the python flask app whose code is given below

```
manager.create_api(SdkProdinfo, 
app=app,methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],

include_methods=["dns_addresses"],

preprocessors={
                'POST': [SdkProdinfo.pre_create_app],
                'DELETE': [SdkProdinfo.pre_delete_app],
                'PUT': [SdkProdinfo.pre_update_app],
                'PATCH': [SdkProdinfo.pre_update_app]
                },

validation_exceptions=[ValidationError])


def pre_delete_app(instance_id, **kw):


        current_app.logger.debug("{0}.{1}: Validating delete prod app request".format(__name__, inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name))

        from . import sdk_prod_count
        from . import sdk_prod_purchase

        # Check if the app is live
        prd_cnt = db.session.query(sdk_prod_count.SdkProdCount).get(instance_id)
        if prd_cnt is None:
            abort(make_response(jsonify(message="No matching prod count"), 400))
        if prd_cnt is not None and prd_cnt.go_live == 1:
            abort(make_response(jsonify(message="Deletion not allowed - app is live"), 400))

        # Check if the app has a purchase history
        purchases = db.session.query(sdk_prod_purchase.SdkProdPurchase).filter(sdk_prod_purchase.SdkProdPurchase.production_nmaid == instance_id).all()
        if len(purchases) > 0: # is not None and prd_cnt.go_live == 1:
            abort(make_response(jsonify(message="Deletion not allowed - app has a purchase history"), 400))

        return request.json['prod_nmaid']
```

But when I try tomake the delete request from the UI, my preprocessor function "SdkProdinfo.pre_delete_app" is not invoked for some reason.

Could someone help me on this ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Are you sure the js is sending the right data?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but the preprocessor would not get called. The deletion process is done directly without preprocessor being invoked. Yes the JS is sending right data. Is there a restriction when a request /api/person/id is made for deletion, id must be a integer ? its a string in my case

Comment: I have always had my Ids as an integer if you are talking about a database primary key. It wouldn't hurt to convert it to an int. Do you have any logging set up?

Comment: Yes I do have it setup, however I don't see any errors getting logged. All I see is the delete request on the logs directly called without the preprocessor